# How to Validate Email Address using RegularExpression validator?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation, email

I have used the below code to validate the email address:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="EmailAddressFormatValidator" runat="server" 
     ControlToValidate="EmailAddressTextBox" 
     ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" 
     Display="Dynamic" 
     ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" 
     EnableClientScript="False">Email Address is not valid.<br />       
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

It is working fine, but when users enters " " (space) in the end of the email, it stops working and declare the valid email to invalid, please help me how i can resolve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `\s*` towards the end of the regex you have

like this

```
\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*\s*
```

i have set up a demo here

http://regex101.com/r/tX7mA8

the regex I have used here is `^\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*\s*$`

I have not much about your language so I suppose those anchor tags are present there for you by default

Comment: Is the question mark necessary? Can you not just add \s* to the end of it?

Comment: ohh hahahaha surely .. I just make some dumb mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

`ValidationExpression="\s*\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*\s*"` in place of your Validation Expression.

Similar questions can be found here:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/

Comment: Hey Aelor, How can you say that "this is wrong", in the question it was written "It is working fine, but when user enters " " space at the end of the email", this clearly shows that he want's space to be optional.

Comment: Sure try understanding wht I am saying, `unless` which means `if not` now since you have the space optional, its correct, but the moment I commented, It was not :)